# Share a directory with one (not all) other non-root user on Linux (no root privileges)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, acl, user-groups

Is it possible to share a directory with one other non-root user, but only this one, without root privileges?

- The system is Ubuntu with kernel 4.4.0.
- I do not have root privileges.
- The system has a large number of users; the administrators would be unlikely to agree to create a new group just for me.
- The system does not allow me to use `setfacl` (probably no acl package installed)

**Approach 1: Using the per-user group (does not work)**

If I had root privileges, I could add the other user to my user group and grant that group the rights to the directory (assume the users are `user_a` (me) and `user_b` (the other) and the directory is `~/shared_directory`):

```
sudo usermod -a -G user_a user_b
```

(this would add `user_b` to group `user_a`, `user_a`'s user group)

```
chgrp user_a ~/shared_directory
```

(this sets the owner group of `~/shared_directory` to `user_a`; in almost all cases this should already be the owner group and the command should not be necessary)

```
chmod g=rwx ~/shared_directory
```

(this gives the group all rights to read, write, and execute (access) the directory).

However, I do not have root access and am not allowed to execute usermod or to write to the relevant file `/etc/group` (which would be bad!).

**Approache 2: Using file access control lists (ACL) (does not work)**

Also, I can neither execute `setfacl` nor locate this executable; probably because the acl package is not installed. I consequently cannot attempt to use the approach suggested [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/759740/164391):

```
setfacl -m u:user_b:rwx ~/shared_directory
```

(This would give `user_b` access to the directory as desired, provided the filesystem and kernel support ACL.)

**My feeling is still that approach 1 (user group and permissions) should be the key to solving this**

Should I not be allowed to control who is part of my user group? Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of the users' identically named user groups?

[Some of the answers to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156473/199642) question in Unix&Linux discussed role, rights, and purpose of per-user groups.

Or is there another way to achieve this that does not require root privileges?

Comment: I suspect you need to work with your sysadmins.

Comment: If the feature is implemented in kernel options (Ubuntu? it is), is not disabled ("noacl" isn't used for /home or alike) and likewise the mount point does allow execution ("noexec" isn't used for /home) then not having the command installed won't prevent to run a local version of the command. You could simply download the packages (including dependencies ), unpack them somewhere in your user directory, and with a few tricks (LD_LIBRARY_PATH ...)  run the command from there. But if this deemed forbidden, the sysadmins could just add the two options above to prevent it anyway

Comment: of course setfacl doesn't require root privileges. having both your account and the other account with a common *dedicated* group does require root privilege to add it. Else you can pick a common generic group if it exists. eg: both users in the cdrom group? that's a common group. Hoping there's no interaction with apparmor/selinux

Comment: @A.B This is a cool idea. I can download and execute `getfacl` and `setfacl`, even without any fiddling with library dependencies. However, you are right that this will not work if it is disabled in the kernel; I am getting `Operation not supported`. Guess that means the kernel does not allow it.